# What to plot in order to pre-analyze the data before building a logistic model?

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization

What to plot in order to pre-analyze the data before building a logistic model?

In linear models I was able to do a scatter plot of just the response values and see, whether they're distributed "reasonably".

However, in logistic models the response is a binary variable and thus produces a kind of difficult to interpret plot of just values $0$ and $1$.

What kind of plots can I do in order to pre-analyze the data before doing a logistic model on it?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a plot?  Why not do cross-tabulations, comparison of means, etc.?  You can also do histograms or box-plots over the two categories of the outcome variable.  Depends on the purpose of doing the plots/bivariate analysis really

Comment: @MarquisdeCarabas No those would be fine as well. I just used plots as an example.

Comment: Examples, with explanation, were provided at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138605, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37683, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14480, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69820.  Many of these will work even for exploratory data analysis ("pre-analysis").